# Shell script to find and count total number of characters in all the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm struggling to make a script to find every file in your home directory that is less than 3 days old and then get a count of the total number of characters in all of these files.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command should work from the current directory.

```
find ./ -ctime -3 | xargs wc -c
```

Below should work for home directory.

```
find ~ -ctime -3 | xargs wc -c
```